# Mi Dialog no se muestra tras haber mostrado otro

Tags: java, dialog

Muy buen día tengan desarrolladores y programadores.

Estoy enfrentando un problema con la clase Dialog. Yo en mi aplicación de Android, tengo 2 variables de Dialog en una misma actividad. Una muestra una lista de participantes en un evento, y la otra muestra una configuración para agregar a la lista anterior.
Mi problema aquí es que cuando presiono el botón para mostrar el Dialog de participantes, se muestra normal, pero al intentar mostrar el segundo, este no se muestra.

En el caso contrario, si presiono primero el botón para mostrar el Dialog de configuración, y luego el botón para mostrar los participantes, ambos se muestran correctamente.

Gracias por su ayuda

Código que uso para mostrar los participantes

```
cd = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditlbActivity.this).create();
LayoutInflater cdLI = getLayoutInflater();
View cdCV = (View) cdLI.inflate(R.layout.listdialog, null);
cd.setView(cdCV);
final Button button1 = (Button)
cdCV.findViewById(R.id.button1);
final Button button2 = (Button)
cdCV.findViewById(R.id.button2);
final Button button3 = (Button)
cdCV.findViewById(R.id.button3);
final ListView listview = (ListView)
cdCV.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
//Start Dialog Logic
availableLists.clear();
loadList.clear();
FileUtil.listDir(FileUtil.getPackageDataDir(getApplicationContext()).concat("/Teams List/"), availableLists);
n = 0;
for(int _repeat35 = 0; _repeat35 < (int)(availableLists.size()); _repeat35++) {
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> _item = new HashMap<>();
        _item.put("list", availableLists.get((int)(n)));
        loadList.add(_item);
    }
    
    n++;
}
listview.setAdapter(new List1Adapter(loadList));
((BaseAdapter)listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
importSbConfig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View _view) {
                            listPath = "";
        cd.dismiss();
                    }
            });
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View _view) {
                            loadList.clear();
        availableLists.clear();
        FileUtil.listDir(FileUtil.getPackageDataDir(getApplicationContext()).concat("/Teams List/"), availableLists);
        n = 0;
        for(int _repeat50 = 0; _repeat50 < (int)(availableLists.size()); _repeat50++) {
            {
                HashMap<String, Object> _item = new HashMap<>();
                _item.put("list", availableLists.get((int)(n)));
                loadList.add(_item);
            }
            
            n++;
        }
        listview.setAdapter(new List1Adapter(loadList));
        ((BaseAdapter)listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
            });
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View _view) {
                            loadList.clear();
        availableLists.clear();
        FileUtil.listDir(FileUtil.getPackageDataDir(getApplicationContext()).concat("/Contestants List/"), availableLists);
        n = 0;
        for(int _repeat62 = 0; _repeat62 < (int)(availableLists.size()); _repeat62++) {
            {
                HashMap<String, Object> _item = new HashMap<>();
                _item.put("list", availableLists.get((int)(n)));
                loadList.add(_item);
            }
            
            n++;
        }
        listview.setAdapter(new List1Adapter(loadList));
        ((BaseAdapter)listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
            });
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> _param1, View _param2, int _param3, long _param4) {
                                final int _position = _param3;
                                
listPath = loadList.get((int)_position).get("list").toString();
        cd.dismiss();
                    }
        });
//End Dialog Logic
cd.setCancelable(false);
cd.show();
cd.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        if (!listPath.equals("")) {
            currentList = new Gson().fromJson(FileUtil.readFile(listPath), new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){}.getType());
            iIT = currentList.get((int)0).get("iconsInTeams").toString();
            currentList.remove((int)(0));
            if (iIT.equals(settings.get("iconsInTeams").toString())) {
                listview1.setAdapter(new Listview1Adapter(currentList));
                ((BaseAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                listUsedT.setText("Lista en uso: ".concat(Uri.parse(listPath).getLastPathSegment()));
            }
            else {
                dialog.setTitle("Error");
                dialog.setMessage("Esta lista no es compatible con los ajustes de la tabla. Seleccione otra.\nIconos: ".concat(iIT.concat(", Tabla: ".concat(settings.get("iconsInTeams").toString()))));
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {
                        
                    }
                });
                dialog.create().show();
            }
        }
    } 
});
```

Código para mostrar los archivos de configuración

```
cd2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditlbActivity.this).create();
LayoutInflater cd2LI = getLayoutInflater();
View cd2CV = (View) cd2LI.inflate(R.layout.listdialog, null);
cd2.setView(cd2CV);
final LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)
cd2CV.findViewById(R.id.linear1);
final ListView list = (ListView)
cd2CV.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
final Button button = (Button)
cd2CV.findViewById(R.id.button1);
//Start Dialog Logic
availableLists.clear();
sbConfigList.clear();
linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
button.setText("Cancelar");
FileUtil.listDir(FileUtil.getPackageDataDir(getApplicationContext()).concat("/Configs/Scoreboards/"), availableLists);
n = 0;
for(int _repeat29 = 0; _repeat29 < (int)(availableLists.size()); _repeat29++) {
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> _item = new HashMap<>();
        _item.put("file", availableLists.get((int)(n)));
        sbConfigList.add(_item);
    }
    
    n++;
}
list.setAdapter(new ScoreboardAdapter(sbConfigList));
((BaseAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> _param1, View _param2, int _param3, long _param4) {
                                final int _position = _param3;
                                
_onListSelected(sbConfigList.get((int)_position).get("file").toString());
        cd2.dismiss();
                    }
        });

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View _view) {
                            cd2.dismiss();
                    }
            });
//End Dialog Logic
cd2.setCancelable(false);
cd2.show();
```

Comment: Podrias indicarnos el codigo de tus Dialogsy la clase desde donde los muestras

Comment: Matías Navarro ya he actualizado el código, si me hace el favor de ayudarme